# Constitutional lawyers and advisers to the architects of new democracies?

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning

> **Despite  the  beliefs  of many constitutional lawyers and advisers to the architects of new democracies** to the contrary, we will see in
>   §7.2.2 that the best evidence currently suggests that these
>   institutional devices have no effect, over and above the effects of
>   democracy generally, in ensuring institutional protections for human
>   rights.
>
> The Moral Foundation of Politics by Ian Shapiro

I'm not sure about the bold area on the above sentence .

I understand there are some beliefs. These beliefs belongs to constitutional lawyers and advisers. And these lawyers and advisers are advising to architects of new democracies.

Am I right or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is "constitutional lawyers" and "advisers to the architects of new democracies" who share the beliefs.

If your interpretation were correct, then you would have "constitutional lawyers to the architects...", which doesn't quite hang together. Usually you have "lawyer for", rather than "lawyer to".

The constitutional lawyers are probably interpreting what constitutions mean after they have been established, rather than providing legal advice on their establishment.

Comment: Thank you very much.